# Is it possible to use one class for both ORMLite and Jackson JSON?

Tags: java, json, sqlite, jackson, ormlite

I want to use ORMLite to query data from SQLite and store it in Java class, then convert this class to JSON using Jackson JSON library and send it through HTTP. I also want to do opposite - get data from server in JSON and convert it to Java class and save this class to SQLite using ORMLite.

Can I do this using one class per table for both ORMLite and Jackson?

Comment: Did you try it? I'd say yes, but I haven't tried.

Comment: I would think that you can use the same object.  The ORMLite annotations and the Jackson annotations should be able to play well together.   Did you try it?

Comment: I am in the process right now, but I can't connect anymore to server, so it will need to wait until tommorow. I will post info here tommorow how it works.

Comment: Beside from internal_error from server I think it works just fine. :) I will answer this question myself when folks repair server and I will be 100% sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, why not? you can convert to json any  java object you want

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);;
```

ORMLite create entity, which is java object so.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "accounts")
public class Account {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String password;
    ...
    Account() {
        // all persisted classes must define a no-arg constructor with at least package visibility
    }
    ...    
}
```

yes you can.